# Do-while loop only iterates once for monthly payment

Tags: c, loops, do-while

I am trying to create a C program which calculates the monthly payment and print a table of payment schedule for a fixed rate loan. My issue is that the loop only iterates once but I cannot figure out why. Here is how the output should looked like: 
[image]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
double calculatePayments(double loan, double rate, int payment);
int main(){
   double loan,rate,monthly,principal,interest,balance;
   int payment, counter;
   counter = 0;
   balance = 0.0;
   printf("Enter amount of loan: ");
   scanf("%lf", &loan);
   printf("Enter interest rate per year:%% ");
   scanf("%lf", &rate);
   printf("Enter number of payments: ");
   scanf("%d", &payment);

   monthly = calculatePayments(loan, rate, payment);

   printf("Monthly payment should be %.2f\n", monthly); 
   printf("—————AMORTIZATION SCHEDULE—————\n ");
   printf("N\tPayment\tPrincipal\tInterest\tBalance\n ");

do{
   rate = rate/12/100;
   interest = loan * rate;
   principal = monthly - interest; 
   balance = loan - principal;
   counter++;
   printf("%d\t%.2f\t%.2f\t\t%.2f\t\t%.2f\n", counter, monthly, principal, interest, balance); 
 }while(balance < 0);

return 0;
}
double calculatePayments(double loan, double rate, int payment) {
   rate = rate/12/100;
   double mul = pow(1+rate, payment);
   return (loan * mul * rate) / (mul - 1);
}
```

Comment: I think your operator is backwards. Change `while(balance < 0);` to `while(balance > 0);`

Comment: the loop will iterate infinitely if i change it

Comment: Then your condition is wrong.

Comment: @begincoding123 Why do you think the loop will be infinite? Also, there's a formula that can give you the number of iterations required for this, something like A=p(1+rt)

Comment: @JReid becaue the loop *is* infinite when the condition is reversed, as per first comment.

Comment: It shouldn't mathematically, but rate is inside the for loop and should be outside.

Comment: I tried that, no difference.

Comment: hmmm ... one second

Comment: just add `loan` to your print statement (or step through with a debugger).. are all those values what you expect? Wouldn't think it'd be terribly difficult to trace back to the origin of the error.

Comment: Had to type the code out, you didn't update loan so balance was always 500-the principal instead of 500-sum of all principals

Comment: i just figured that too. the loan was always 500 and never updated...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing up the do ... while loop

```
// e.g. 7.5/12/100 = 0.00625
rate = rate/12/100;
do{
   // e.g. 500*0.00625=3.125
   interest = loan * rate;
   // e.g. 101.88-3.125=98.76
   principal = monthly - interest; 
   // e.g. 500-98.76=401.24
   balance = loan - principal;
   // update loan
   loan = balance;

   counter++;
   printf("%d\t%.2f\t%.2f\t\t%.2f\t\t%.2f\n", counter, monthly, principal, interest, balance); 
 }while(balance > principal);
```

Comment: I still only get one payment after updating the loan

Comment: I too err'd in not updating `>`

Comment: I changed the operator to balance > 0 and it worked but it added an extra payment with negative balance

Comment: Sorry I don't have a compiler right now so I can't test this stuff but I'm thinking if monthly >= balance we should exit the loop yes? Given your example you have a 6th payment with a balance of -0.01?

Comment: It was over -100. I've changed the operator to balance > principal and the output came out correctly. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Balance would never be `< 0`.  That is why you loop is only running once.  If you had done a `while` loop instead of `do while` it wouldn't run at all.

Change `balance < 0` to `balance > 0`

Answer (score 1):

You are checking to loop only if balance is less than Zero.

but at the first iteration the value of balance would be 401$ (not < 0)
So breaking.

You should be checking for balance > 0 in while